# Filtering dictionary based on first key in a tuple key (key1, key2), where key1

Tags: python

I have a dictionary pair_counts['key1, key2':'valueA'] and a dictionary item_counts['key3':'valueB'].  I need to create a new dictionary reduced_pair_counts['key1, key2', 'valueA] where key1 is in item_counts['key3']

I'm new to python, so I'm just not sure how to access the first key in a tuple key.

I need a new dictionary where the key/svalues are the same as pair_counts, but only if the first half of the tuple-key is somewhere in item_counts[key]

Comment: {key:value for key, value in pair_counts.items() if item_counts.get(key[0], None)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First be careful about notations.

```
pair_counts = {(key1, key2):valueA,...}
item_counts = {key3:valueB, ...}
```

you want:

```
new_dict = {key:value for key, value in pair_counts.items() if key[0] in item_counts}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response.  I've never posted on Stack Overflow before, and I clicked the arrow to the left of the post... I think that means I selected the best answer?  Anyway, it worked.  Thanks again.